# Code Execution in Form Stops

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I'm writing an application which is supposed to communicate with a windows mobile 6.5 device. When the device is plugged in, the activeHandler callback is returned.
The problem that I'm having is that code execution stops at the

```
lblStatus.Text = "someString";
```

line. No Exception is thrown, the code execution is justed stopped and the gui gets the focus. I've tried the same thing with using the invoke method on the label property which yielded the same result. If calling non form code in that method, everything runs fine.

```
public partial class MyClass: Form
{
    public MyClass()
    {
           ActiveHandler active = new ActiveHandler(ActiveSync_Active);
           sync.addHandler(active)
    }

    private void ActiveSync_Active() {
        lblStatus.Text = "someString";
        //Some code
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
The invoke call that didn't work

```
private delegate void StatusLabelChange(string str);
private void ChangeStatusLabelText(string str)
{
    lblStatus.Text = str;
}

private void ActiveSync_Active() {
    lblStatus.Invoke(new StatusLabelChange(ChangeStatusLabelText), new object[] {"asd"});
 }
```

Comment: it sounds like it must be thread related, i.e. the thread making the callback isn't the main GUI thread. Strange that Invoke doesn't work though... how about setting up some kind of thread-safe queue to pass data from the callback back into the GUI thread?

Comment: Can you tell me what type is "sync" variable? What classes/library do you use?

Comment: sync is my own class using the OpenNETCF Desktop Communication Library (http://rapi.codeplex.com/) to communicate with the device

Comment: Can you post the `Invoke` call that didn't work for you?

Comment: Could it be that an Exception is thrown but is silently swallowed by some handler?

Comment: @Bobby How could you find out?

Comment: @Alexander Stolz: If you don't know about it, then it's not the case. On the other hand, does your IDE break on exceptions?

Comment: @Bobby Yes it does, I'm using Visual Studio 2k5

Answer (score 0):

Try BeginInvoke too, since that'll push it async.